# Tensorflow - ImportError: SystemError: <built-in method __contains__ of dict object at 0x00000244B47ADDB8> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7

I am taking this error, My versions like below;

Python Version 3.7
Tensorflow Version 2.8.0

File "C:\Users\ABC1\Anaconda3\envs\DevArea3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in 
from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
File "C:\Users\ABC1\Anaconda3\envs\DevArea3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\pywrap_tf_session.py", line 19, in 
from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import *
ImportError: SystemError: <built-in method **contains** of dict object at 0x00000244B47ADDB8> returned a result with an error set

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the NumPy version is not the required one.  Upgrading NumPy may solve the issue.  The upgrade can be achieved through the following command within Anaconda Prompt:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Comment: I had numpy 1.19 that didn't work, upgrade installed 1.21 and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the location where your packages are installed on your machine (given in the file path in the error) and deleting any duplicates you don't need. Turns out my requirements.txt file was installing versions of packages that didn't match some of the default versions, and when I thought I was "replacing" them, I was actually creating duplicate installs of the same package. Notice how I had multiple numpy's. Only keeping the numpy I needed resolved a few of those errors for me.

[Look at image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz3qx.jpg)